# get id from first select for next select statements

Tags: sql

i need to select  three results from three different tables in a stored proc. second two table records can only be queried with tabela_id. Cannot do a join, since need three different datasets.  i tried declaring a variable and selecting that value to tablea's id but sql woulnt allow that

```
select tablea_id, xyz, member_id
from tablea
where @member_id = tablea.member_id

select table2_id, abc, tablea_id
from tableb
where tableb.tablea_id = **tablea_id**

select tablec_id, aggg, tablea_id
from tablec
where tablec.tablea_id = **tablea_id
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would make it easier for us!

Answer (score 0):

MS Sql Server can be done like this:

```
select table2_id, abc, tablea_id
    from tableb
    where tableb.tablea_id = (
    select TOP 1 tablea_id from tablea where @member_id = tablea.member_id
    )

    select tablec_id, aggg, tablea_id
    from tablec
    where tablec.tablea_id = (select TOP 1 tablea_id from tablea where @member_id = tablea.member_id)
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.